# After upgrade to Windows 10, some programs can't be uninstalled

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-10, installer

I had the same issue with several programs since I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 (x64), but right now it's VirtualBox:

I previously had VirtualBox 4.2.16 installed, then came the Windows upgrade, and now I just downloaded VirtualBox 5.0.8.

The installer tries to uninstall the old version first, but fails when it can't be removed. I also can't remove the program from the Control Panel - Programs and Features. The error that occurs is that it tries to locate an MSI file which isn't there, and prompts me to specify another location:

[image: The feature that you are trying to use ...]

I don't have this file, how can I fix this?

Comment: download it then point the prompt to it.

Comment: I tried that, but the file is different from the 4.2 download.

Comment: I wonder if a third party uninstaller might help.

Comment: I tried CCleaner, but it just starts the original uninstaller.

Comment: [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) is fantastic (last I used it) at removing left over files and registry keys. It'll prompt the original installer first, then just close it and let it scan your system for left over files. Probably the best you can get for a third party uninstaller. It's not free but I believe there's a trial.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up searching the registry for VirtualBox entries, and found an entry that referred to the path shown in the error message. After deleting it, and manually deleting the files from the program folder, I tried Uninstall from Programs and Features again, and it removed VirtualBox from the list. After that, The installation of the new version worked.